Regarding anagarika and monastery life
Does anyone know if becoming an anagarika in a Theravada monastery is only allowed temporarily or could one become a anagarika and stay in a monastery indefinitely?
Also what concessions are given to anagarikas in a monastery life.

Anagarika status is intended for people considering ordination,  a chance to try out monastic life, somewhere between a lay person and ordained.
Perhaps what you are asking is whether it's possible to stay in a monastery long term as a lay person. Yes, it is possible depending on the place. There would need to be demonstrated a commitment to living a monastic lifestyle obviously. Most monasteries in the west would welcome such a person if they were a good fit.

I was more inquiring about if one decided only to take certain vows and live as an anagarika rather than take the full vinaya commitments and become a novice-full ordination. Of course not everyone would want to become a monk but still may want to live a reclusive and/or restrained life.

I don't think anagarikas, novices or monks take "vows" at least not anywhere I've been, and I'm a long term monk.

Vows and precepts are synonymous. Take the precept of celibacy as according to the vinaya, this is a vow to abstain from sexual activity. An anagarika becomes a homeless one and gives up the householder life, as too does a monk, but a monk takes the full vinaya precepts where an anagarika takes only the 8 precepts. Personally I see fruitlessness in the entire vinaya. Some precepts are antiquated like "not putting salt in a horn" like anyone is western society even has an average ability to do such a thing. Though I would take vows seriously and would not want to make vows I could not keep.

near 300 in the vinaya. IMO too many to even keep count of mentally. though of course most would be not broken by default. i.e one would have to purposely go out of their way to break the precepts. Like the salt in a horn precept.  More importantly in western society abandoning being able to "touch gold and silver" i.e not touch or use money at all, can lead one to death, which is akin to suicide, as not all people in our societies are benevolent enough to feed one another. So one needs money to survive. unless of course living within a specific community, a monastery for example.
